# How to make sure data structure can fit data from huge file?

Tags: c++

I have a system where `streampos` is 64-bit but `size_t` is 32-bit. I need to load big files. The project is sometimes compiled as 32-bit and sometimes as 64-bit.

I want to write code that fails nicely if the size of the file is too big to store in a single data structure. I'm concerned about how the size types may get casted in the wrong way. Please take a look at the sample code and comment on how to make it safe for this case.

```
ifstream file;
vector<char> data;

// find size of file
streampos beg = file.tellg();
file.seekg(0, ios_base::end);
streampos end = file.tellg();
file.seekg(0, ios_base::beg);

// prepare vector
if (data.max_size() > (end - beg)) { throw "blah"; } // warning: signed/unsigned mismatch
data.resize(static_cast<vector<char>::size_type>(end - beg)); // what happens if the size is more than 32-bits?

// copy data
file.read(&data[0], data.size());
```

Comment: if `end-beg` can't fit into a `vector::size_type`, then it will _necessarily_ also be greater than `vector::max_size()`.  I think you're completely fine here. (well, assuming it's positive, but that's also a safe assumption)

Comment: Unrelated, I always used `unsigned char` for bytes, so then you _can't_ pass it to any string functions without an explicit cast.

Comment: @MooingDuck Hi. I need to put a cast here as there is a warning. What do you recommend? Also, how can I load a file into a vector of unsigned char efficiently without reinterpret_cast?

Comment: I think your cast is perfect.  This is _exactly_ what `static_cast` is for.  To cast from one static type to another, after you've assured that it will definitely succeed.  To read in the file into a vector of `unsigned char`, you _should_ be using a `reinterpret_cast`, not avoiding it.

Comment: @MooingDuck I need another cast on the indicated line

Comment: `(end-beg)` is of type [streamoff][1] which is signed.  `max_size()` is size_t which is unsigned. This is why the warning   [1]http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/streamoff/

Comment: @Christophe Yes I understand the warning, I want to know how to fix the code so it doesn't warn.

Comment: The standard says that *streamoff is a synonym for one of the signed basic integral types of sufficient size to represent the maximum possible file size for the operating system*. If it's integral and with bigget capacity than unisgned int,  the best should be:  `std::streamoff(data.max_size())>(end-beg)`.  Is this what you are looking for ?

Comment: @Christophe If that's the correct way to make my code safe, then yes.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in your text I understand that you want to throw if the content of the file is bigger than the max size of the data.

So instead of

```
if (data.max_size() > (end - beg)) // triggered whenever the file could fit in memory !!
    { throw "blah"; }
```

I'd strongly recommend

```
if (data.max_size() <  (end - beg)) // < instead of > 
    ...
```

Now, how to get rid of the warning ?

data.max_size() is of type `size_type` which is an unsigned integer type (C++11, section 23.2.1).

end and beg are both `streampos`, which are themselves some `fpos` (C++11, section 27.3). Thus the difference (end - beg)  is of type `streamoff` (according to C++11, section 27.5.4.2).

A `streamoff` is itself a synonym for one of the signed basic integral types of sufficient size to represent the maximum possible file size for the operating system (C++11, section 27.5.2).

As both types are integer types, you can convert one to the other (C++11, section 4.7 pt 1).  The standard states that *if the destination type is signed, the value is unchanged if it can be represented in the destination type* (same section, pt 3).

Given the respecive bitsize that you mention, you could safely rewrite:

```
if (streampos(data.max_size()) < (end - beg))
```

or

```
 if (static_cast<std::streamoff>(data.max_size() < (end - beg))
```

Now it is surprising that your compiler doesn't make the conversion itself.  Under MSVC13 I didn't get the warning.

Last remark:  if (end-beg) would be greater than allowed by size_type , you would have thrown an exception.  Thus if you arrive at the next line:

```
data.resize(static_cast<vector<char>::size_type>(end - beg)); // if unsafe, the previous line would already have thrown an exception !
```